# Entity not Found Error in Google Classroom when creating assignment with STUDENT_COPY material

Tags: google-classroom

I'm programmatically submitting a Google Classroom assignment, and I'm seeing different behavior when attach a Material using the STUDENT_COPY shareMode than when I use the VIEW shareMode.

The following code seems to be working fine:

```
var resource = {
    title: name,
    description: explanation,
    workType: 'ASSIGNMENT',
    state: 'PUBLISHED'
};

resource.materials = [];
resource.materials.push({
    driveFile: {
        driveFile: {
            id: 'fileId'
        },
        shareMode: 'VIEW'
    }
});     
var params = {auth: creds, courseId: courseId, resource: resource};
classroom.courses.courseWork.create(params, function (err, courseWorkResponse) {
  /* handle response */
}
```

With that code, the assignment gets created and I can see it in Google Classroom. However, if I set the shareMode to STUDENT_COPY instead of VIEW, I get the following error:

```
{ Error: Requested entity was not found.
    at Request._callback (/Users/.../node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/.../node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users.../node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
  code: 404,
  errors:
   [ { message: 'Requested entity was not found.',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'notFound' } ] }
```

The assignment is not being created in Google Classrom. However, I *am* seeing a [Template] copy of the Google Doc I specified in the driveFile.id being placed into my Google Drive.

I've tried this with several different documents, some of which were basically "Hello World"-level google docs, so I doubt the issue is related to the document.

Other than that, I'm not sure what could be going on. I assume there must be some sort of permissions issue somewhere, but does anybody else have a clue what might be going on?

EDIT: Further information

It seems to be an issue with "publishing" the assignment. If I set the `resource.state` to `DRAFT`, I'm able to successfully execute the `coursework.create` API call. I get back an instance of a CourseWork object as expected.

The problem is I need to ultimately PUBLISH the assignment. And when I try to execute the `classroom.courses.courseWork.patch()` api call to simply change the state from DRAFT to PUBLISHED, I end up getting the same `Requested entity was not found` error.

However I am able to go into Google Classroom itself, view my drafts, and click on the ASSIGN button in the application. If I do that, everything finally works! That UI flow is no good for me, though. But it does indicate that there's nothing inherently wrong, as far as I can tell, with the assignment. I just seem to be missing some (undocumented?) step that's necessary in my case.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem without going into Google Classroom?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because entity does not exist yet because the students haven't accessed the assignmend yet in the classroom. So make sure they do and try again.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/classroom/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Classroom_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1AssignmentSubmission.html):

> Drive files that correspond to materials with a share mode of
>   STUDENT_COPY may not exist yet if the student has not accessed the
>   assignment in Classroom.